# Positive linear combination of vectors to produce a positive vector

Tags: vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a list of vectors, I want a linear combination with positive coefficients that produces a final vector with only positive values (EDIT: this final vector is unknown; any positive vector is viable). If it's known that such a solution exists, any suggestions on an algorithm to find such a combination?

Comment: This can be expressed as a linear program.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood, are you trying to solve $\sum_k \alpha_k v_k = b$, where $\alpha_k \ge 0$? Or are you trying to see if the convex cone generated by the vectors intersects the interior of the positive quadrant?

Comment: Where b is unknown, yes. Any positive a that produces a positive b is acceptable. (editing question for clarity)

Comment: Solve $\min_{\alpha,x} \{ \alpha | -e_k^T A x -\alpha \le 0, x \ge 0 \}$. If the minimum is $<0$ then a solution exists, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: It's known that a solution exists, I'm curious how to find it. (out of curiosity, what does that expression actually represent? What is the e_k there?)

Comment: $e_k$ is the vector of zeros except for a one in the $k$th position. I am sure there are more efficient and direct solutions, but the LP approach will work and is in Matlab, Octave, etc.